# Attach .m and .h files to a storyboard's TabBar Controller

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I've implemented a new part of my application made by .m .h and xib (yeah, it's old) with storyboard, in particular a view with a tabBar controller and 2 item linked to it. I instantiate the storyboard with:

```
NVPassportViewController *passportBookController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NVPassportViewController" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"passportViewController"];
```

Now, I know that I can attach .m and .h files in the tabBar controller of the storyboard, setting "custom class" to `NVPassportViewController`, but the `viewDidLoad` method of  `NVPassportViewController` is never called with the tabBar of the storyboard on screen. Why? linking the tab1's and tab2's view to specific .m and .f files is working, but with main tabView controller no.

EDIT: solved and i think that's a important know-how for custom class and storyboard: you can't name your Storyboard file and custom class with the same name.

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be creating the view in question as a subview. I believe you will find that viewDidLoad is being called on the subview before the parent view, which may map to your description that it "is never called with the tabBar of the storyboard on screen".

Without knowing what functional problem this is causing, it's hard to suggest a specific solution, though it is quite likely that some combination of `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` and the correct use of dependency injection may resolve your problems... :)

Comment: so you think that i can instantiate `NVPassportViewController` firstly and implement `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` on its .m file to load view from storyboard? Have you some link with tutorials about that?

Comment: This one looks alright... disclaimer: didn't read it properly to check :) http://nscookbook.com/2012/12/ios-programming-recipe-3-creating-segues-with-the-storyboard-part-1/

Comment: I've looking to this tutorial but it's not my problem: I'm not coming from view's storyboard to sequential storyboard's view. My problem is that i programmaticaly load a Storyboard for a part of my project instantiating it like: `[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NVPassportViewController" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"passportViewController"];` but this type of instance doesn't call my custom class of `NVPassportViewController`